# Is it possible to list the checkboxes that are checked in a textbox

Tags: c#

I have a `page` where the user can select what toppings they would like, I would then like the next form to have a `textbox` with all the `Checkboxes` listed that the user checked in the previous form, is this possible?

I have made it work with one `Checkbox` checked using the following code,

On form 1,

```
public static string Cheese = "";

 if (CheeseTick.Checked)
        {
            Cheese = "1 x Extra Cheese";
        }
```

on form 2,

```
ToppingSummary.Text = Form1.Cheese
```

Comment: There are tonnes of ways to concatenate strings e.g. `Form1.Cheese + Form1.Toppings` etc...

Comment: What do you mean by "Form" ? Is it Web Form(ASP NET) or Windows Forms form ? And why Cheese is static ?

Comment: @MajkeloDev its windows forms, and i dont really know, i found the code online!

Comment: whatever was done there - it's wrong. Can you send me a link to the place you found it ? I assume that Form2 is instantiated from Form1 so during this instatiation Form1 should pass data to Form2 with constructor or some public property on form 2. Reading this from a static property is terrible.

Comment: Its very very (epically) badly designed but not wrong , it will work as long as you use it in the right way. but that is truly awful

Comment: I usually use a List<CheckBox> that I can enumerate through.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that you have to enumarate all the `Control`s and filter out `CheckBox`es of interest:

```
   public class Form1 {
     ...
     public static IEnumerable<Control> AllControls(Control control) {
      var controls = control.Controls
        .OfType<Control>();

      return controls
        .SelectMany(ctrl => AllControls(ctrl))
        .Concat(controls);
     }

     public String AllToppings {
       get {
         var source = AllControls(this) 
           .OfType<CheckBox>()
           .Where(checkbox => checkbox.Checked)
           //TODO: put other conditions on checkbox here, e.g. 
           //.Where(checkbox => checkbox.Name.Contains("Tick")) 
           .Select(checkbox => checkbox.Text); 

         return String.Join(" ", source);
       }  
     } 
     ...

   }
```

On the `Form2`

```
   Form1 form = Application.OpenForms
     .OfType<Form1>()
     .LastOrDefault();

   if (form != null)
     ToppingSummary.Text = form.AllToppings;
```

Answer (score -1):

The Correct way to do this is MVVM, that is that the form has an object on it that has its value set on the form, that change is then picked up on a second form because it has the same object inside it

```
public class FoodOrder
{
    public List<String> SpecialInstructions{get;set;}
    public void AddSpecialInstruction(string instruction)
    {
        SpecialInstructions.Add(instruction);
        SpecialInstructionsChanged?.Invoke(this,EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    public event EventHandler SpecialInstructionsChanged;
}
```

then in form one CheeseTick.CheckedChanged event calls AddSpecialInstruction or RemoveSpecialInstruction, form two listens to SpecialInstructionsChanged and updates as required

```
public class Form1
{
    public FoodOrder Order {get;set}
}

public class Form2
{
    public FoodOrder Order {get;set}
}
```

then you do `form2.Order = Form1.Order` just make sure you add a listener to the event after you sent the orders to be equal

if you then wanted to automate the checkbox's you can loop through all the checkboxes in the designated control

```
foreach(Checkbox c in Control.Controls)
{
    c.CheckedChanged += (s,e)=>
    {
        var cb = s as Checkbox;
        if(cb.Checked)
            Order.AddSpecialInstruction(cb.Text);
        else
            Order.RemoveSpecialInstruction(cb.Text);
    }
}
```